# Double jump in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an 2D platformer were I want my character to be able to doublejump.

With this code my character can double jump but depending on how quick I press the jump button the second jump will make the character to jump more than twice as high compared to if I were to wait to press the jump button.

How do I make so the second jump can't be higher than the first one?

```
[SerializeField] float maxSpeed = 10f;              // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.
[SerializeField] float jumpForce = 400f;            // Amount of force added when the player jumps. 

[Range(0, 1)]
[SerializeField] float crouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%

[SerializeField] bool airControl = false;           // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
[SerializeField] LayerMask whatIsGround;            // A mask determining what is ground to the character

Transform groundCheck;                              // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
float groundedRadius = .2f;                         // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
bool grounded = false;                              // Whether or not the player is grounded.
Transform ceilingCheck;                             // A position marking where to check for ceilings
float ceilingRadius = .01f;                         // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
Animator anim;                                      // Reference to the player's animator component.

int maxNumberOfAirJumps = 1;                        // Number of times the player can jump in the air
int numberOfAirJumpsLeft = 0;



void Awake()
{
    // Setting up references.
    groundCheck = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
    ceilingCheck = transform.Find("CeilingCheck");
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundedRadius, whatIsGround);
    anim.SetBool("Ground", grounded);

    // Set the vertical animation
    anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
}


public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{    
    // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
    if(!crouch && anim.GetBool("Crouch"))
    {
        // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
        if( Physics2D.OverlapCircle(ceilingCheck.position, ceilingRadius, whatIsGround))
            crouch = true;
    }

    // Set whether or not the character is crouching in the animator
    anim.SetBool("Crouch", crouch);

    //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
    if(grounded || airControl)
    {
        // Reduce the speed if crouching by the crouchSpeed multiplier
        move = (crouch ? move * crouchSpeed : move);

        // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        // Move the character
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if(move > 0 && !facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if(move < 0 && facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
    }

    // If the player should jump...
    if (grounded && jump) {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        anim.SetBool ("Ground", false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce));
        numberOfAirJumpsLeft = maxNumberOfAirJumps; //Reset the air jumps when the player jumps
    }
    else if (!grounded && jump && numberOfAirJumpsLeft  > 0)
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce));
        numberOfAirJumpsLeft--; //One less jump 
    }
}


void Flip ()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{

    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        //money collected

        //destroy money object
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ".. and sorry for the bad format." - Apology accepted. Now instead of apologizing for this, go fix it ;)

Comment: Depending on how you want it to be. When the player does a second jump, you'll need to cancel all forces from the first jump and add the second jump like normal. In other word, when the player does a second jump, just pretend he is resting on a solid platform and is jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Is `FixedUpdate` called before each `Move`?  If so, it resets grounded based on the radius, so you could get in a second "grounded" jump if you are fast enough.  Then, you could do one more airjump.

Comment: FixedUpdate runs once every physics frame (Every time the game physics updates) which can happen a couple times per rendered frame

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at game development, so I will make a suggestion that I think should work.

You need to reduce `jumpForce` after the first jump or add less force after each air jump. It should be something like this:

```
//Declare int numberOfAirJumpsMade = 1;
if (grounded && jump) {
    // Add a vertical force to the player.
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", false);
    rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce));
    numberOfAirJumpsLeft = maxNumberOfAirJumps; //Reset the air jumps when the player jumps
    numberOfAirJumpsMade = 1; //reset air jump counter
}    
else if (!grounded && jump && numberOfAirJumpsLeft  > 0)
{
    rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce / (numberOfAirJumpsMade * 2)));
    numberOfAirJumpsLeft--; //One less jump 
    numberOfAirJumpsMade++;
}
```

Here you adding in the first air jump 2 times less force than you did in jump from ground. If you set `maxNumberOfAirJumps = 2` then first air jump gets `(400 /(1 * 2)) = 200` force and second gets `(400 /(2 * 2)) = 100`.

This is just to get you started. Later you may want to add gravity force in calculations because when your hero is landing you probably want to add far less force for air jumps.